# Start and stop activity indicator swift3

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I am learning Swift and now working on my home task. 
One of my buttons calls a function where I reload a collection view and it takes time. I am trying to implement an activity indicator to show the process.
The problem that if I start the indicator, load the collection view, and then stop the indicator within the button action, the indicator doesn't appear.
What would be the correct way to implement the indicator in this case? 
Here is the piece of the code:

```
let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge)
@IBOutlet weak var onCIFilterView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet var cifilterMenu: UIView!

@IBAction func onCIFiltersButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (sender.isSelected) {
        hideCIFilters()
        sender.isSelected = false
    }
    else {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        showCIFilters()  //the menu with UIView collection
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        sender.isSelected = true
    }
}

func showCIFilters () {
    onCIFilterView.reloadData() // reloading collection view
    view.addSubview (cifilterMenu)
    let bottomConstraint = cifilterMenu.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainMenu.topAnchor)
    let leftConstraint = cifilterMenu.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor)
    let rightConstraint = cifilterMenu.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor)
    let heightConstraint = cifilterMenu.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([bottomConstraint, leftConstraint, rightConstraint, heightConstraint])
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

func hideCIFilters () {
    currentImage = myImage.image
    cifilterMenu.removeFromSuperview()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //.....
    activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width/2, y: view.bounds.size.height/2)
    activityIndicator.color = UIColor.lightGray
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
}
```

Comment: Try stopping the activity indicator after the collection view has reloaded - I'd guess at the end of the showCIFilters method.

Answer (score 11):

The problem you are facing is that UI changes like starting an activity indicator don't take place until your code returns and the app serves the event loop.

Your code is synchronous, so the activity indicator never gets called.

You need to start the activity indicator spinning, return, and then do your time-consuming activity after a delay. You can use `dispatch_after` for this (or `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` in Swift 3).

Here is an example `IBAction` that runs an activity indicator for 2 seconds after tapping a button:

```
@IBAction func handleButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
  activityIndicator.startAnimating()
  sender.isEnabled = false
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {

    // your time-consuming code here
    sleep(2) //Do NOT use sleep on the main thread in real code!!!
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    sender.isEnabled = true
  }

}
```

### Edit:

Your code would look like this:

```
@IBAction func onCIFiltersButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (sender.isSelected) {
        hideCIFilters()
        sender.isSelected = false
    }
    else {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.0) {
            showCIFilters()  //the menu with UIView collection
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            sender.isSelected = true
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit #2:

Again, UI changes don't actually take place until your code RETURNS and the app services the event loop

If you have code like this:

```
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
sleep(2)  //This is in place of your time-consuming synchronous code.
activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
```

Then what happens is this:

You queue up a call to start the activity indicator the next time your code returns. (So it doesn't happen yet.)

You block the main thread with some time-consuming task. While this is going on, your activity indicator has not started spinning.

Finally your time consuming task completes. Now your code calls `activityIndicator.stopAnimating()`. Finally, your code returns, your app services the event loop, and the calls to start and then immediately stop the activity indicator get called. As a result the activity indicator does not actually spin.

This code does it differently:

```
//Queue up a call to start the activity indicator
activityIndicator.startAnimating()

//Queue up the code in the braces to be called after a delay.
//This call returns immediately, before the code in the braces is run.
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
    showCIFilters()  //the menu with UIView collection
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    sender.isSelected = true
}
```

Since closure passed into the call to `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` is not run right away, that call returns immediately.

The app returns to service the event loop, and the activity indicator starts spinning. Shortly after that, Grand Central Dispatch invokes the block of code that you passed to it, which begins running your time-consuming operation (on the main thread) and then makes a cal to stop the activity indicator once the time-consuming task has completed.

Comment: Makes sense.  I looked in the docs to determine if reloadData was sync or async but it didn't say.  Thanks for clearing it up for me.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me, though only after I added a delay to the deadline like .now() + 0.01. I am reading the documentation about DispatchQueue and still struggling to understand how exactly suggested solution works. I understand that commands inside DispatchQueue braces are run asynchronously and the code return after they are all completed. But what makes activityIndicator.startAnimating() get called with the delay and why it doesn't get called without it?

Comment: If you have code like this: `start_animating;do_time_consuming_task;stop_animating`, then you never return and service the event loop after starting the activity indicator before doing your time consuming task. Thus it never starts spinning, and then you stop it from spinning before it actually starts. In the code I posted, you start the activity indicator spinning, then queue up the call to do you time consuming task after a brief delay. Your function then returns, your app services the event loop, and the activity indicator begins spinning.

Comment: See Edit #2 to my answer.

Comment: Superb! This should be the accepted answer. Thanks @DuncanC

Answer (score 1):

Here's one thing you can try: 
- I have created a custom loading view and have shown and hidden it on button clicks. You can show and hide based on your particular needs. For a full working demo you can see this repo on github - [NKLoadingView in swift](https://github.com/nikeshkrjha/NKLoadingView)

```
import UIKit

class NKLoadingView: UIView {

let width: CGFloat = 150
let height: CGFloat = 60
let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 15
let spacing: CGFloat = 20
var label = UILabel()
var fontSize: CGFloat = 20
var isVisible: Bool = false


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
    let viewFrame = CGRect(x: 50, y: window.frame.height / 2 - height / 2, width: window.frame.width - 2 * 50, height: height)
    super.init(frame: viewFrame)
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func setupView(){
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.65).cgColor
    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .white)
    spinner.startAnimating()
    spinner.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(20), y: CGFloat(10), width: 40, height: 40)

    label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: spinner.frame.origin.x + spinner.frame.width + spacing, y:  spinner.frame.origin.y, width: self.frame.width - spacing - spinner.frame.width - 20, height: spinner.frame.height))
    label.text  = "Please Wait..."
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)

    self.addSubview(spinner)
    self.addSubview(label)
}

func stopAnimating(){
    isVisible = !isVisible
    self.removeFromSuperview()
}

func startAnimating(message: String){
    label.text = message
    isVisible = !isVisible
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.addSubview(self);

 }
}

//View Controller code
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var loading: NKLoadingView?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loading = NKLoadingView()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

@IBAction func startEndAnimation(_ sender: Any) {
    if !loading!.isVisible {
        loading?.startAnimating(message: "Please Wait....")
        (sender as! UIButton).setTitle("Stop Animation", for: .normal)
    }else{
        loading?.stopAnimating()
        (sender as! UIButton).setTitle("Start Animation", for: .normal)
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Duncan C is right, you should be doing your time consuming activity asynchronously. However, the best way to implement that is to add in a completionHandler to the `onCIFilterView.reloadData()` function. This way you can stop the activity indicator at the moment the data reload completes. There's a good tutorial on completionHandlers here: https://grokswift.com/completion-handlers-in-swift/

Also, I think there's something else going on here as well. If you can't see it, that because your CIFilterView is on top of it in the UI view stack. You'll need to bring that forward. To do this you'll need to call something like:

```
view.bringSubview(toFront: activityIndicator)
```

or

```
view.superclass?.bringSubview(toFront: activityIndicator)
```